# How do I compile an AVI file from a bunch of bitmaps in C# ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, avi

Yes, I've already heard of http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/avifilewrapper.aspx
...but I just can't get it to work with ASP.NET

I've perused the source about a hundred times looking for anything that might suggest it's incompatible with .NET 3.5 or not going to work with my other frameworks. Everything seems Kosher.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Comment: I think the problem might be with AviFil32.dll -- though there aren't any exceptions when I import it. I think this is the standard Microsoft AVI library. Anyone know if it works with ASP.NET?

Comment: I'm curious about your problem.  Did you ever solve it?  Did you find another library?

Comment: Thanks @Eugenio, I've been working on the BMP to PDF conversion since that's significantly easier. But I found some different libraries like LEADTOOLS that seem to work okay. I'm going to try using the above library as a windows CLI tool. I think that might be the key. I'll pass jobs to it and query the result from my ASP.NET page.

Answer (score 2):

Do you know what exceptions are being thrown?  The AviFileWrapper you mentioned I believe depends on libraries provided by the windows API, and those libraries might not be available in your server, especially for ASP applications.

If you need a solution badly enough, you might consider writing a simple library yourself.  The AVI format might be simple enough to implement it yourself, given that you might not need sound or compression.

Here is some documentation I found.

www.alexander-noe.com/video/documentation/avi.pdf

Good luck.

Comment: Wow-- that's a great guide. Thanks :) I'll look into it. I wrapped every possible section in a try...catch block and even made some the functions in question give a return value of an array of the bitmaps I made, just to make sure it thinks it's succeeding too. No exceptions, no warnings, just one frustrated (junior) developer.

Comment: It sucks when code ought to throw exceptions and it doesn't, or when they are not informative...  It happens more often when working with windows API stuff.  I once used the library you cited, and not without trouble.  The problem is not with that particular project but with the underlying libraries that it uses...  There's got to be an open source project that you could adapt.